# Concurrency in the Task-based API in Azure SDK for .NET

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I currently have a couple of concurrency issues with the Task-based asynchronous API in the Azure SDK for .Net version 3.0.2-prerelease.

I have a list of web site names

```cs
var webSites = new [] { "website1", "website2" };
```

and from these, I'm using the task based API to create or delete the WebSites. Both occasionally fail:

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(webSites.Select(x => webSiteClient.WebSites.CreateAsync(
    "westeuropewebspace",
    new WebSiteCreateParameters
    {
        SiteMode = WebSiteMode.Limited,
        ComputeMode = WebSiteComputeMode.Shared,
        Name = x
        WebSpaceName = "something"
    }
)));
```

Seldom, I get an exception complaining that the Server Farm "Default1" already exists. I get that this server farm is implicitly created for Free web sites, but there is currently no way to create this Server Farm through the API before creating the WebSites (only the "DefaultServerFarm" can be).

When deleting, something similar happens:

```cs
await Task.WhenAll(webSites.Select(x => webSiteClient.WebSites.DeleteAsync(
    "westeuropewebspace",
    x,
    new WebSiteDeleteParameters
    {
        DeleteAllSlots = true,
        DeleteEmptyServerFarm = true,
        DeleteMetrics = true,
    }
)));
```

Often (about every second time), I get an Exception that "website2" could not be found, although it definitely existed. The WebSite is deleted, though.

**Update**:
I have serialized this second Task.WaitAll into a foreach-loop and I still get the exception. The only difference now is that when deleting "website1" fails, "website2" still exists in the cloud (because the second delete request is not sent) and I have to delete it manually through the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - the create site api also tries to create a server farm implicitly and if called concurrently that may cause conflicts. A safer way is to create a server farm explicitly using API and then use that server farm when creating web sites. That way you explicitly control the placement of sites to server farms and there are no implicit server farm creations.

The Azure SDK API contain a method to create server farm explicitly.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/WebSiteManagement/Generated/ServerFarmOperations.cs

Comment: *grmbl*: I'm already creating "the" server farm using the API, but there is currently no way to create WebSites immediately linked to this server farm (even if you specify "DefaultServerFarm" in the WebSiteCreateParameters they end up "Free"). You have to create them and then update to get "Shared" WebSites. On the other hand, the API cannot create the "Default1" Server Farm for "Free" WebSites, so you end up not being able to create the required Server Farm before creating WebSites concurrently in any way.

Comment: Hi Kai, unfortunately this is how API works if older API version is used. I believe the SDK has not been updated yet to use the latest API version. When you create site in older API version the three parameters control the placement of the site to the server farm: ComputeMode, SiteMode, ServerFarm. In newer API version the ComputeMode and SiteMode are ignored.

When you create a site can you try to also specify the ComputeMode as "Dedicated"? That way the computeMode for the site will match the computeMode of the serverFarm so the site should be placed correctly.